# Сохранение скомпилированных webpack-dev-middleware файлов

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

В дев режиме для компиляции использую `webpack-dev-server` с `webpack-dev-middleware` (с `express`'ом). Требуется получить доступ к скомпилированным файлам.
Как заставить `webpack` сохранять файлы на диск, когда используется `webpack-dev-server`?

Comment: Зачем это требуется? Если в это появилась реальная необходимость, то видимо пора отказываться от webpack-dev-server и пользоваться напрямую webpack-dev-middleware или вообще честно компилировать результаты в файл, а для ускорения использовать опцию watch

Comment: Честная компиляция в файл и так есть, для прод. конфига, а webpack-dev-middleware нужен именно для разработки. Что касается файлов, то тут виновата кривая архитектура, которую я уже исправил, но вопрос остался. Кстати Илья Кантор в своем скринкасте вроде упоминал о возможности сохранения на диск, но не сказал как.

Comment: Судя по исходникам, нужно отредактировать `webpack-dev-middleware`: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware/blob/master/middleware.js#L33 заменить на `var fs = require("fs");`

Comment: Хорошая попытка, но в стандартной поставке `fs` нет метода `mkdirp`, так что просто так оно не заведется. Нужно напильником подпилить. Большое спасибо, @BobSponge, за подсказку, в каком направлении копать )